# Can you use Bootstrap for layout in a HotTowel view?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hottowel

Here's my HotTowel view:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">One</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Two</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">Three</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Four</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This does not render right using bootstrap with HotTowel.  You don't get the expected bootstrap table layout.

If I do this:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">One</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Two</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">Three</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Four</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

in a plain html page in the same project, the bootstrap table layout is as expected.

Am I missing something that HotTowel needs to use bootstrap for a view layout?  The bootstrap css and js files are all referenced in HotTowel's index.cshtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap in a HotTowel view. The issue may come from your bootstrap loading scenario.

- Have a look to your **bundleConfig** : bootstrap may be defined after jquery.
- Make sure you **correctly render** the bundle containing bootstrap in your index.cshtml.
- Make sure bootstrap is **not loaded more than once**.

Comment: bootstrap is defined after jQuery in the ScriptBundle.  When I place it before jQuery, it still comes out after jQuery on the page.  I checked the page for duplicates of bootstrap.js and didn't find any.  As far as my view goes, I don't think it could be any more simple.  It's just a 2 row, 2 column layout.

Comment: I tried using span1, span3, etc... and those classes where used by bootstrap.  It's when I try to use col-lg-4, col-lg-6, etc... that bootstrap is not working.

Comment: span1, ...,span3 are for bootstrap 2.3.x and col-lg-4,...,col-lg-6 are for bootstrap for 3.1.x so its depends to your library version.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved.  I was trying to use the new col* classes for layout and HotTowel is only using version 2.3.2 of bootstrap.  I switched to using the span* classes and everything started working.